# Custom Gutenberg block with nested InnerBlocks renderAppender not displaying add button

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm converting a carousel/slider from a [shortcode](https://github.com/PHuhn/WordPress-Child-Theme-Addons) to a Gutenberg block.  I got the first Gutenberg version working, but I want to convert that to use a **InnerBlocks** template, so the rich-text blocks can use the native toolbar (bold/italic/alignment/etc).  So the base **slider block** now uses an **InnerBlocks** to render the template.  I've added an additional block to render the **items**, which contains an **InnerBlocks**.  The **items** block allows three blocks that each contain an **InnerBlocks**.  The three blocks are **slider item**.

```
Slider (with Innerblocks template)
  Slider Items (InnerBlocks with allows 3 different blocks)
    Slider Item (3 different blocks each with an InnerBlocks)
```

The problem is the **Slider Items** does not seem to display the **plus sign** to add one of the 3 different **Slider Item**.

`gc-slider2/block.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "give-camp/gc-slider2",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "GC Slider 2",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "slides",
    "description": "Generic slider",
    "attributes": {
        "role":         { "type": "string", "default": "" },
        "ariaLabel":    { "type": "string", "default": "Marketing data" },
        "milliSec": { "type": "number", "default": 5000 },
        "borderColor":  { "type": "string", "default": "000000" },
        "height":       { "type": "string", "default": "460px" },
        "width":        { "type": "string", "default": "100%" },
        "unit":         { "type": "string", "default": "px" }
    },
    "supports": {
        "type": "object",
        "anchor":   true,
        "ariaLabel": true,
        "color":    {
            "color":        true,
            "background":   true,
            "link":         true,
            "gradients":    false
        },
        "typography": {
            "fontSize":     true,
            "lineHeight":   true
        },
        "dimensions": {
            "minHeight": true
        },
        "spacing": {
            "margin": true,
            "padding": true,
            "__experimentalDefaultControls": {
                "padding": true
            }
        },
        "__experimentalBorder": {
            "color": true,
            "style": true,
            "width": true,
            "radius": true,
            "__experimentalDefaultControls": {
                "color": true,
                "style": true,
                "width": true,
                "radius": true
            }
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "give-camp-blocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

`gc-slider2/index.js`

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
import {
    registerBlockType
} from '@wordpress/blocks';
//
import metadata from './block.json';
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InspectorControls,
    InnerBlocks
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
//
import './style.scss';
//
function Slider2Edit(props) {
    //
    const {
        attributes: { role, ariaLabel, milliSec, height, unit },
        setAttributes,
        textdomain,
        clientId,
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'gc-slider',
        role: role,
        "aria-label": { ariaLabel},
        "data-millisec": { milliSec }
    });
    // Create a template of InnerBlocks with predefined attributes
    const SLIDER_TEMPLATE = [
        ['core/heading', // header
            {
                placeholder: __("header title ..."),
                level: 2,
                className: 'gc-slider-header'
            }
        ],
        ['give-camp/gc-slider-items', {} ],
        ['core/paragraph', // footer
            {
                placeholder: __("footer title ..."),
                tagName: 'div',
                className: 'gc-slider-footer',
            }
        ]
    ];
    //
    return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
            >
            <InnerBlocks
                template={SLIDER_TEMPLATE}
                templateLock="all"
            />
            <div
                className="gc-slider-counter has-text-align-center"
                style={ { paddingTop: "3px", paddingBottom: "6px" } }
                >1 of ?
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    //
}
//
function Slider2Save( props ) {
    //
    const {
        attributes: { role, ariaLabel, milliSec, height },
        textdomain,
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: 'gc-slider',
        role: role,
        "aria-label": { ariaLabel},
        "onMouseOver": "gc_slider_hover(this)",
        "onMouseOut": "gc_slider_hover_leave(this)",
        "data-millisec": { milliSec }
    });
    //
    return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
            >
            <InnerBlocks.Content />
            <div
                className="gc-slider-counter has-text-align-center"
                style={ {paddingTop: "3px", paddingBottom: "10px" } }
                >1 of ?
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    //
}
//
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    apiVersion: metadata.apiVersion,
    title: metadata.title,
    supports: metadata.supports,
    attributes: metadata.attributes,
    //
    edit: Slider2Edit,
    save: Slider2Save,
} );
```

`gc-slider-items/block.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "give-camp/gc-slider-items",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "GC Slider Items",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "align-pull-left",
    "description": "Item wrapper for sliders' individual content",
    "attributes": {
        "allowedBlocks": { "type": "array", "default": [
            "give-camp/gc-slider-item",
            "give-camp/gc-slider-right-2-columns",
            "give-camp/gc-slider-left-2-columns"] }
    },
    "supports": {
        "anchor":   true
    },
    "textdomain": "give-camp-blocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

`gc-slider-items/index.js`

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
import {
    registerBlockType
} from '@wordpress/blocks';
//
import metadata from './block.json';
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InnerBlocks,
    ButtonBlockAppender,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
//
import './style.scss';
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637842/how-to-pass-attributes-to-child-gutenberg-blocks-in-innerblocks-template
function SliderItemsEdit(props) {
    //
    const {
        attributes: { allowedBlocks },
        usesContext
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'gc-slider-items',
        "aria-hidden": 'false',
        "aria-roledescription": 'carousel'
    });
    //
    return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
            >
            <InnerBlocks
                orientation="horizontal"
                allowedBlocks={ allowedBlocks }
                renderAppender={ () => <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender>
                        { __('Add Item') }
                    </InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender>
                }
            />
        </div>
    );
    //
}
//
function SliderItemsSave( props ) {
    //
    const {
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: 'gc-slider-items',
        "aria-hidden": 'false',
        "aria-roledescription": 'carousel'
    });
    //
    return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
            >
            <InnerBlocks.Content
                orientation="horizontal"
            />
        </div>
    );
    //
}
//
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    apiVersion: metadata.apiVersion,
    title: metadata.title,
    supports: metadata.supports,
    attributes: metadata.attributes,
    //
    edit: SliderItemsEdit,
    save: SliderItemsSave,
} );
```

`gc-slider-left-2-columns/block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "give-camp/gc-slider-left-2-columns",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "GC Slider Fade-in Left 2 Column Item",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "align-pull-left",
    "description": "Item wrapper for sliders' individual content",
    "attributes": {
        "style": {
            "type": "object",
            "default": {
                "core/button" : {
                    "border" : {
                        "radius" : "8px"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "anchor":   true
    },
    "textdomain": "give-camp-blocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:../gc-slider-utils/style-index.css"
}
```

`gc-slider-left-2-columns/index.js

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
import {
    registerBlockType
} from '@wordpress/blocks';
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InnerBlocks
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import metadata from './block.json';
import '../gc-slider-utils/style-index.css';
import {
    textGroupColumnTemplate,
    imageColumnTemplate,
    textImageAllowedBlocks,
} from '../gc-slider-utils/gc-slider-data';
//
function Slider2LeftColumnsEdit(props) {
    //
    const {
        attributes: { fadeInDirection },
        setAttributes
    } = props;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( );
    //
    return (
        <InnerBlocks
            { ...useBlockProps }
            template={ [
                [ 'core/columns', { className: ['gc-slider-item', 'wp-block-columns', 'is-layout-flex', 'wp-block-columns-is-layout-flex'],
                                    style: { display: 'none' } },
                    [
                        [ 'core/column', { className: ['gc-fadeInLeft', 'gc-is-visible', 'gc-slider-2-column-image', 'wp-block-column', 'is-layout-flow', 'wp-block-column-is-layout-flow'],
                                    style: { width: '50%' } },
                            imageColumnTemplate
                        ],
                        [ 'core/column', { className: ['gc-fadeInLeftBig', 'gc-is-visible', 'gc-slider-2-column-title', 'wp-block-column', 'is-layout-flow', 'wp-block-column-is-layout-flow'],
                                    style: { padding: '0px', width: '50%' } },
                            textGroupColumnTemplate
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ] }
            allowedBlocks={ textImageAllowedBlocks }
        />
    );
}
//
function Slider2LeftColumnsSave( props ) {
    const {
        attributes: { fadeInDirection },
    } = props;
    //
    const _displayNone = {
        display: "none",
    };
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: 'gc-slider-item',
        style: _displayNone
    });
    //
    return (
        <InnerBlocks.Content
            { ...useBlockProps }
        />
    );
}
//
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    apiVersion: metadata.apiVersion,
    title: metadata.title,
    supports: metadata.supports,
    attributes: metadata.attributes,
    //
    edit: Slider2LeftColumnsEdit,
    save: Slider2LeftColumnsSave,
} );
```

The **gc-slider-right-2-columns** is basically the same as the above except the image is on the right and the animation is the opposite.

`gc-silder-utils/gc-slider-data.js`

```
export const animationClasses = [
    { value: '',                label: '- none -' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeIn',       label: 'Fade In' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInBig',    label: 'Fade In Big' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInLeft',   label: 'Fade Left' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInLeftBig', label: 'Fade Big Left' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInRight',  label: 'Fade Right' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInRightBig', label: 'Fade Big Right' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInUp',     label: 'Fade Up' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInUpBig',  label: 'Fade Up Big' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInDown',   label: 'Fade Down' },
    { value: 'gc-fadeInDownBig', label: 'Fade Down Big' },
];
/**
** values for selection of animation dropdown
*/
export const onScrollShowClasses = [
    { value: 'gc-show-on-scroll',   label: 'Show On-scroll' },
    { value: 'gc-show-once-on-scroll', label: 'Show Once On-scroll' }
];
/**
** Aria Values ... values for selection of type/role dropdown
*/
export const sliderRoles = [
    { value: 'img', label: 'Images' },
    { value: 'list', label: 'Content' }
];
/**
** gc slider right & left 2 columns text template
*/
export const textGroupColumnTemplate = [
    [ 'core/group', { className: [ 'gc-slider-2-column-title-group', 'gc-slider-2-column-title-group-button-center' ] }, [
            [ 'core/spacer', { height: '50px' } ],
            [ 'core/heading', { level: 3, align: 'center', placeholder: 'Item Title ...' } ],
            [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Item description ...' } ],
            [ 'core/button', { text: 'Action', align: 'center', style: { border: { radius: '8px' } } } ],
        ]
    ],
];
/**
** gc slider right & left 2 columns image template
*/
export const imageColumnTemplate = [
    [ 'core/image', { } ],
];
/**
** gc slider right & left 2 columns allowed blocks
*/
export const textImageAllowedBlocks = [
    'core/column',
    'core/columns',
    'core/heading',
    'core/paragraph',
    'core/group',
    'core/spacer',
    'core/image',
    'core/button',
    'core/buttons',
];
// End-of-file ...
```

Comment: In `gc-slider2/index.js`, I removed the **templateLock="all"** from the **InnerBlocks**, and it is now displaying the plus sign for the `gc-slider-items` block.  Which leaves me with a different problem of two add block plus signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `gc-slider2/index.js`, I removed the **templateLock="all"** from the **InnerBlocks**, and it is now displaying the plus sign for the **gc-slider-items** block.

```
    <InnerBlocks
        template={SLIDER_TEMPLATE}
        allowedBlocks={ [ ] }
    />
```

Which leaves me with a different problem of two add block plus signs.  [See Gutenberg Innerblocks notallowedblocks on parent but allowedblock on child](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/419043/gutenberg-innerblocks-noallowedblocks-on-parent-but-allowedblock-on-child)